# Отследить, что и где обращается к элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно отследить, какая функция обращается и что делает с каким-то элементом? У меня в проекте возник баг, суть которого заключается в том, что определённому инпуту присваивается значение, которое присваиваться не должно. Хочу отследить, что, как и когда делает с этим инпутом. Есть ли такой функционал в отладчике браузера, например? И как это вообще можно отслеживать?

Comment: 1) Убедиться, что значение добавляется не с бэкенда. 2) Ctrl+F по id, class'у или тэгу инпута. - это если по-народному.

Comment: Вроде в MutationObserver нужная функциональность есть https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver Может, в коллбеке получится стек отпечатать

Comment: Подобные ситуации - чёткий сигнал, что пора немного порефакторить

Comment: @Darth на самом деле, проблема скорее всего не в моём коде, а в плагине flatpickr, который я использую. В данном случае речь идёт о проблеме [#625](https://github.com/chmln/flatpickr/issues/625). Плагин почему-то подставляет год туда, куда этого делать не надо. Если его отключить от страницы, то проблема исчезает. Вот и пытаюсь отследить, что именно создаёт проблему и починить это пул-реквестом.

Comment: [Такой код](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688280) не поможет?

Comment: Где-то здесь был ответ о том, что для такого можно использовать Event Listeners в браузере. Но ответ почему-то удалили(то ли сам автор, то ли модерация). Ответ был отчасти правильным, потому что благодаря именно Event Listeners я нашёл место возникновения проблемы.